# MS Access queries running extremely slow after migrating to Windows Server 2012

Tags: ms-access, windows-server-2012

We have recently migrated our application server environment to Windows Server 2012 from Windows Server 2008.

One of our .Net console applications which runs MS access queries is returning the data very slowly after the migration.

It is taking over 10 minutes to run a simple access query which used to run in less than few seconds earlier on Windows Server 2008 machine.

Can anyone provide any inputs on what could be the reason for this slowness, and also let me know the areas I should be looking at to resolve this issue.

More details:

There are no hardware changes. DNS servers are not in scope for this as this is a stand-alone console based application. We have installed 64-bit MDAC 10 driver to make connectivity to the MS Access database from our Console application. The Provider we are using in our connection string is "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0". Also, we are using OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader() method to fetch the data from the access queries.

Comment: Did any hardware change ? DNS Servers updated ?

Comment: There are no hardware changes. DNS servers are not in scope for this as this is a stand-alone console based application.

Comment: I'd make an educated guess at security permission differences in behaviour, if nothing else is obvious. It sounds as if something is taking its time authenticating somewhere down the line.

Comment: What is the "Bitness" of the Access DB 32 or 64 bit ?

Comment: It is a 64-bit Access DB.